# Why doesn't my screen have the color I set for it?

Tags: pygame

I am trying to create a green background for the screen of my game.

```py
class Sky: 
    """Project the stars to the screen"""
    
    def __init__(self): 
        """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior""" 
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sky full of stars")
        self.bg_color = (0, 250, 0)
        self.stars = pygame.sprite.Group()
    
    def show_screen(self):
        """Start the main loop of the game"""
        while True: 
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
```

When I initiate the game the screen color is black even though I have set it to green.